# No Terraform/Cloudformation in Sonarqube 9.5?

Tags: terraform, sonarqube, aws-cloudformation

Good day,

Recently we have upgraded our SonarQube to version 9.5 (build 56709) and we were hoping to start scanning Terraform files however we are missing both Terraform and Cloudfomation languages.
Worth to mention that our SQ is running in a docker with the following image - sonarqube:9.5.0-community

I’ve created a git repository with a simple main.tf file and trigger a pipeline to push the code to the SonarQube to perform a scan, but I’ve received `The main branch has no lines of code`

Then, I’ve checked Administration → General Settings → Languages and noticed that we are missing exactly those 2 languages in the list - Terraform and Cloudformation

I’ve also tried to find something related in the SQ community or Stackoverflow, but no luck :(

According to the [official announcement](https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-9-2/) SQ supports TF and CF after version 9.2.

Any help or assistance would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

[no terraform or cloudformation in sonarqube 9.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK9Uy.jpg)

Comment: If its open source, ask on github issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to SQ Community!
We've been using /lib/ folder as persistent volume.
Removed that volume and redeployed, now everything is working like a charm